# Google Charts API with SQL data in Python

Tags: python, json, flask, google-visualization

I have looked over the other questions addressing this, but they don't answer my questions specifically.
I am trying to use data returned from SQL in Flask, and passing it to the Google Charts API.  It's a basic weight/calorie tracker, and I need to return date and weight for the chart. My `userdata` for one user returns from SQL query

`db.execute("SELECT * FROM history WHERE id = :id", id=session["user_id"])`:

`[{'id': 1, 'weight': 180, 'calories': 2100, 'rewards': 1, 'date': '2018-04-14'}, {'id': 1, 'weight': 185, 'calories': 1800, 'rewards': -1, 'date': '2018-04-15'}, {'id': 1, 'weight': 180, 'calories': 1600, 'rewards': 1, 'date': '2018-04-13'}, {'id': 1, 'weight': 180, 'calories': 1900, 'rewards': -2, 'date': '2018-04-12'}, {'id': 1, 'weight': 186, 'calories': 1111, 'rewards': 5, 'date': '2018-04-16'}, {'id': 1, 'weight': 184, 'calories': 1200, 'rewards': 5, 'date': '2018-04-17'}, {'id': 1, 'weight': 184, 'calories': 1400, 'rewards': 3, 'date': '2018-04-18'}, {'id': 1, 'weight': 180, 'calories': 2100, 'rewards': -4, 'date': '2018-04-11'}]`

I am not familiar with PHP which I see pop up often, but I am OK with Python, and just learning JavaScript.  It appears I need to jsonify the data to pass, but I'm not sure how to do that.
I read through the Google Charts documentation, but I'm still not quite sure how to pass this info into the chart code.

Any help you can give is MUCH appreciated!

*************Edited with updated code*************
OK, I think I have the data formatted correctly, and returning json.dumps().  I can get the Google Charts to display a chart with manually entered data in the script, but when I pass the variable to use I get `undefined: Request could not be proxied!` error in Chrome when I try to access the page.  Here is a larger snippet of my code, I hope it helps.  (I'm new to programming, so please keep that in mind :/)

Python route - this returns what I initially put:

`@app.route("/charting", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def charting():`

```
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM history WHERE id = :id", id=session["user_id"])

jsonData = (json.dumps(rows))

return render_template("charting.html"), jsonData
```

JavaScript - works with manually entered data, but doesn't work with the passed variable .done(function (jsonData):

```
  // get data
  $.ajax({
    url: '/charting',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function ({{ jsonData }}) {
  });

  // load json data
  function loadData(jsonData) {
    $.each(jsonData, function(index, row) {
      data.addRow([
        row.date,
        row.weight,
        row.calories
      ]);
    });
    drawChart();
  }
```

Am I passing the variable correctly? I should be passing the JSON version of the data, and it should parse everything according to the data.addcolumn descriptors.

Comment: Add the code you made so far.

Comment: I just updated the post with my current python and javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use separate files for your python and html / javascript...

in python, for the data you posted above,
use `json.dumps` to json encode the data,
then return / print it to the page...

```
import json

... db code ...

return json.dumps(dataFromQuery)
```

see [JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html)

---

in html, use jquery ajax to get data from python...

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'path to python',
  dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (jsonData) {
  // jsonData is what python returns
});
```

---

in order to create a google data table directly from json,
the json must be in a specific format, found here...
[Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

if you can change the python to format the data accordingly,
you can create the chart's data table like so...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

otherwise, you will you need to load the data table manually,
something like this...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
data.addColumn('number', 'Calories');

$.each(jsonData, function(index, row) {
  data.addRow([
    row.date,
    row.weight,
    row.calories
  ]);
});
```

---

see following working snippet,
since the path to python doesn't exist,
the example will use hard-coded data,
which can be removed...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  // create chart
  var container = $('#chart_div').get(0);
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
  var options = {
    legend: {
      position: 'top'
    }
  };

  // create data table
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Calories');

  // get data
  $.ajax({
    url: 'path to python',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    loadData(jsonData);
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var jsonData = [{'id': 1, 'weight': 180, 'calories': 2100, 'rewards': 1, 'date': '2018-04-14'}, {'id': 1, 'weight': 185, 'calories': 1800, 'rewards': -1, 'date': '2018-04-15'}, {'id': 1, 'weight': 180, 'calories': 1600, 'rewards': 1, 'date': '2018-04-13'}, {'id': 1, 'weight': 180, 'calories': 1900, 'rewards': -2, 'date': '2018-04-12'}, {'id': 1, 'weight': 186, 'calories': 1111, 'rewards': 5, 'date': '2018-04-16'}, {'id': 1, 'weight': 184, 'calories': 1200, 'rewards': 5, 'date': '2018-04-17'}, {'id': 1, 'weight': 184, 'calories': 1400, 'rewards': 3, 'date': '2018-04-18'}, {'id': 1, 'weight': 180, 'calories': 2100, 'rewards': -4, 'date': '2018-04-11'}];
    loadData(jsonData);
  });

  // load json data
  function loadData(jsonData) {
    $.each(jsonData, function(index, row) {
      data.addRow([
        row.date,
        row.weight,
        row.calories
      ]);
    });
    drawChart();
  }

  // draw chart
  $(window).resize(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: `$.ajax({  url: 'path to python',  dataType: 'json'}).done(function (jsonData) {  // jsonData is what python returns});`
If you have a webpage needing data returned from python, it will need to be running a webserver of some kind, like flask... I don't think this method is what OP is asking for.

Comment: @WhiteHat that is extremely helpful!  I appreciate the links, but more importantly the explanations. 
It will take me a bit to work this into my code, but I should have something by tomorrow.
I am using flask so it should be fine.

Comment: @WhiteHat, I pasted your code into my HTML and everything worked great with the manually entered data, so I started tinkering with my code.
I checked my jason.dumps data 'jsonData' and its formatted correctly. I changed the ajax url to my `/charting` route.  I also removed the script after `}).done(function (jsonData) {`, which I assume is just there for entering the data manually.
I use Flask's `return render_template("charting.html"), json.dumps(jsonData)' to pass the data and generate the page.
I keep getting a Flask proxiy error. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Maybe I need a separate scripts.js for my html to reference?

Comment: that shouldn't matter, but i'm not familiar with flask -- if you leave the `fail` callback on the `ajax` call as above, you can look for errors there, add this line in `fail` callback --> `console.log(errorThrown);`

Comment: I still can't seem to get my jsonData returned to javascript correctly.  I tried using jinja to pass it as {{ jsonData }}, and tried creating a separate .js file to reference, but I still can't get it passed.  Any other suggestions?
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I tried that with `jsonData = jsonify([rows])`, but got the same result.
I'm sure i'ts something syntax related, but I can't figure out how...

Comment: OK, I still can't get it to work.  I had the thought that it's not able to return the JSON data through a regular call.  Can AJAX call a function where I can return the JSON data, or is there a way to set the /charting route up to recognize an AJAX call vs a GET/POST?  That way I can return both within the same route.